What is significance of FrozenSetMember on entities introduced with v10 Guidewire Application
New upgraded code added FrozenSetMember delegate to many of the OOTB entities. Would like to understand significance of this new entity and example of real time usages.
Any reference to GW documentation will be appreciated.
Searched through GW product documentation and didn't much information

An entity needs to be included in the account transfer graph if it’s created on policy period creation or it’s created specifically for a policy period.
If the entity needs to be included in the graph, the fix is simply implementing the delegate, FrozenSetMember, in the entity.
Reference GW Article # 000027403
Hope it helps. Cheers!
